# Let Inbox button in messenger start outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-live-messenger

Is it possible to press the `Inbox` button from Windows Live Messenger 2011 and start Outlook instead of Windows Live Mail?

Outlook 2010 is my default e-mail software, but it still starts Windows Live Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the registry pretty deeply, and the Live Messenger settings myself, and could not find a thing, so I checked the Internet. This seems to be a very common request (to open Outlook, or even gmail in a web browser), but I found more than one Microsoft MVP (so they tend to be pretty good with MS products), who confirmed what I thought: You can't do it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the search. I did some searching as well and couldn't find it either. I think I'll switch back to live mail then \*sigh\*. If it were just a bit faster with startup, everything would be fine, but ok. Thanks anyway.